# How to block outgoing connections from AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

The networking tab firewall is to control incoming connections. But I can't find any setting to block outgoing connections. How do I block outgoing connections to certain IPs from AWS Lightsail?

Answer (score 0):

There is no lightsail way of blocking outgoing connections.

You will have to use the hosted OS's firewall functionality to block outgoing connections.